# check if data exists in firestore document else push to an array

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I want to check if the data exists in the firestore document, if it does not, then I want to push it to an array.

In the code below, I want to check if q1,q2,q3,q4,q5 exists in the database. The database is structured like this:

```
firestore /users/userID/post/PlMGiyQRDZuKGipTu5sl/
{ question:'q2'
  answer: 'answer to q2'
}



let questions = [q1,q2,q3,q4,q5];
let questions_subset = [];
questions.forEach((item, index) => {

    let query = db.collection('users').doc('userID').collection('post').where('question', '==', item).get();
    query.then(snapshot => {
        if (snapshot.empty) {
            console.log('No matching documents.');
            questions_subset.push(item);
            return;
        }
        snapshot.forEach(doc => {
            console.log(doc.id, '=>', doc.data());
        });
        return
    }).catch(err => {
        console.log('Error getting documents', err);
    });
    console.log(questions_subset);
})
```

Right now, console.log(questions_subset) gives me an empty array. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your promise chain starting with get() is all asynchronous and returns immediately, progressing immediately to the console log of questions_subset, which is initially empty.  You're going to have to make that log only after the async work is complete, which means learning better how to work with promises.

Comment: Hi, I've seen Doug's comment and it seems to address why your code was behaving unexpectedly. Do you still need an answer or the issue solved as of today?